Migrating Angular 13 to Angluar 18
I am using with angular 13
https://github.com/bbc/slayer

Its a commonjs lib and has no @types.I Managed to make it work with angular 13 (a while back) but now with the vite compiler I just dont know how.
I added "types": ["node"] to tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json
add declared a type.d.ts
declare module 'slayer';
but nothing works
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/slayer/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js

How can I import properly a commonjs module in my angluar 18 app ?
Thanks

I have created a reference example. Tell me know if you need more help. 
Slayer example Angular 18
src/app/slayer.d.ts
declare module 'slayer' {
      export interface SlayerConfig {
        minPeakDistance: number;
        minPeakHeight: number;
        transformedValueProperty: string;
      }
      export class Slayer {
        constructor(config: SlayerConfig);
        fromArray(array: number[]): Promise<any>;

        // add other methods that you need
      }
    }

...
src/app/process.d.ts
declare module 'process';

angular.json
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application";

to
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"

Change browser to main
"browser": "src/main.ts"; => "main": "src/main.ts";

Add polyfills.ts
"polyfills": ["src/polyfills.ts"]

Create file src/polyfills.ts
import 'zone.js';
...

(window as any).process = {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: '', // to avoid undefined.slice error
};

declare in tsconfig.app.json
"files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts" // <= add
]

Install
npm install util

